# Multi cURL function not working in XAMPP localhost

Tags: multithreading, curl, xampp

XAMPP Version: 1.8.1
PHP Version: 5.4.7

I'm using the following cURL class: http://semlabs.co.uk/journal/object-oriented-curl-class-with-multi-threading

Class source code: http://paste2.org/XGeMUMme

In XAMPP, when I attempt to do a multi curl session, the page never loads and my CPU usage goes up and doesn't stop until I end the Apache process; however, when I run the code on my webhost, it works perfectly.

**The following works in XAMPP, because it's a single-threaded cURL execution**

```
$curl = new CURL();  
$opts = array( CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true  );  
$curl->addSession( 'http://yahoo.com/', $opts ); 
$result = $curl->exec();  
$curl->clear();
```

However, when this code is ran (only adding one more session, which makes it multi-threaded), the page is never loaded as I stated previously.

```
$curl = new CURL();  
$opts = array( CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true  );  
$curl->addSession( 'http://yahoo.com/', $opts ); 
$curl->addSession( 'http://google.com/', $opts ); 
$result = $curl->exec();  
$curl->clear();
```

Although, the above code does work on my website.

Any ideas and/or solutions regarding this problem? Thank you!

Comment: check http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php

Comment: @Akam Well, I don't think the error lies within the code itself as it works on my webhost.

Answer (score 0):

for multi curl , the curl_multi_select() always returns -1 , which causes to end the execution time
 you should use you own sleep time usleep(100);